# Calculating voltage loss using impedance of a system

Tags: voltage, impedance

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKjqsi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So I'm trying to figure out the Total impedance Z of a system with a capacitor in series with a resistor and inductor, where the resistor and inductor are in parallel.

The total impedance I got is

\$Z=0.08587...Ohm < 89.8679°\$

and the calculations for it are (a bit trimmed from the actual calculations for your convenience):
\$R = 8Ohm\$

\$L = 2mH\$

\$C = 10uF\$

\$f = 10kHz\$

\$U_{in}=1Vpp\$

\$R = 8Ohm\$

\$X_C = 2πfC = 0-j7.9577... Ohm < -90° \$

\$X_L=\frac{1}{2πfL} = 0+j25.1327... Ohm < 90°\$

\$Z=X_C+\frac{RX_L}{R+X_L}\$

\$Z=9.1999...Ohm < -37.8539°\$

With the total impedance I figured I could calculate the current based on \$U_{in}\$, but the current I get is above \$10A\$, which would put the voltage drop on \$X_C\$ alone above what the value of \$U_{in}\$ is.

Am I misunderstanding something on how I should use the value \$Z\$, or am I misunderstanding the answers of my calculations?

Again, I'm trying to calculate the voltages \$V_C, V_R, V_L\$ and I assume that \$V_R=V_L\$

Edit:

With the newly found impedance, I was able to calculate

\$I= 0.07686... A <37.8539° \$

and

\$V_C =  0.6116... V < -52.1461° \$

Assuming that it's correct in the first place, how should I proceed to calculate the phase shift of the voltage drops in V_R and V_L? Is it simply a sum with the phase shift natural to that component with the phase shift of the components prior to it (in this case, \$XC\$)?

Meaning:

\$V_L = 0.7071V-0.6116V  <(-90°-(-52.1461°))  = 0.0955V <37.8639°\$

\$V_R = 0.7071V-0.6116V<-52.1461° = 0.0955V<-52.1461°\$

Comment: *a system with a capacitor in series with a resistor and inductor, where the resistor and inductor are in parallel.* To avoid all confusion, please draw a schematic. There's a schematic entry tool for that available when you **Edit** your question.

Comment: You are using L in the formula for Xc and C in the formula for XL.

Comment: Fixed (I hope, at least)